# Wrong scope being returned when requesting token

Tags: python-3.x, office365api

I'm trying to build an O365 service status portal for users in my company. Only admins can see the admin portal status page, but we want to provide that info to our users/display on a dashboard.

I've registered the app in Azure, and given it the correct permissions according to the documentation. I can request an auth code and I'm able to use it to retrieve a JWT, but when the token is returned to me, I'm only seeing User.Read in the scope, meaning I'm unable to use it for any of the functions in the ServiceComms API.

Here's the snip of code being used to retrieve the token:

```
url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>/oauth2/token'
r = requests.post(url, dict(resource='<appid>',
client_id='<clientid>',
redirect_uri='http://x.x.x.x/365/auth/index.htm',
client_secret='<itsasecret>',
grant_type='authorization_code',
code=auth_code))
```

Here's the first part of what's returned:

```
{"token_type":"Bearer","scope":"User.Read","expires_in":"3600","ext_expires_in":"0","expires_on":"1525266602","not_before":"1525262702",
```

The account being used to retrieve the auth code initially is a global admin on the tenant, so would expect that this would be fine, but I'm new to this, so probably wrong.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you've set the appropriate permissions on your app registration in the Azure portal, and your question is why they don't show up in the token.

I've seen this behavior before with the Azure v1 endpoint if the user you login with had previously consented to the `User.Read` permission, then you updated the required permissions in the portal. While it's logical to assume that Azure would detect this change and re-prompt, it doesn't. It keeps returning tokens based on the previously recorded consent and doesn't pick up the new ones.

To handle this, your app must include the `prompt=consent` query parameter on the URL during the authorization phase. That should force consent when the user logs in and pick up the new permissions.

Comment: Yeah, I set the appropriate permissions for the app.

I think there may be something wrong with my code, not sure what.